# run jar file from python with os.system

Tags: java, python, cmd, system

I try to run a jar file with `os.system('java -jar file.jar')` and print libraries errors(not path or filename error).

However the same file run with windows cmd with the the command `'java -jar file.jar'`.

Can someone help me? I use the `open-JDK "1.8.0_232"` .
Thanks for yours time .

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: (1) *Don't* use `os.system()`. The `subprocess` module should be used instead for all new code. (2) Figuring out what's going wrong requires comparing environment variables between the working and broken contexts, and looking at the specific error message you're encountering. Without the environment variables or a specific error message, there's nothing here for anyone to go off of in building an answer.

Comment: thanks you for yours time i make a restart and now the jar run (may this happened  because i edit the system variables without restart )I will change the system with subprocess thanks again